# Best way to make my Flash AS3 App into a Desktop App?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a Flash application that I made and I want to basically take it and make it into a desktop app using my Flash file... (assuming user has Flash installed on PC) What would be the best way of simply taking a Flash web app and making into a desktop one (that doesn't require any other runtime besides flash for the user).

Comment: Run the SWF with the local Flash client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/).

Comment: +1 Skilldrick | If you use a PC FlashDevelop (http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) is an excellent AS3 code editor that comes packaged with an Air template that is idiot proof.

Comment: +1 for Adobe AIR - a great way to make desktop app from online, works superb for us at http://www.comapping.com for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three options,

1. flash includes a "flash projector" which turns a flash file into a stand alone exe file and is included with flash.
2. Use adobe air to make a desktop application. But it's a little more work that dropping the flash file in and it does require another runtime (although it will be automatically installed if flash exists on the machine so may not be an issue)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the following tools:

Jugglor: http://www.flashjester.com/

Zinc: http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/